# how to restrict direct access to url in spring

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, spring-security

In a web application, when a user visits a students list page, the screen shows list of student names with hyperlinks. Only those student names are shown which the user is allowed to see. When user clicks on the hyperlink, a new window opens showing the details of the user. The child window's address bar shows the url as follows.

myhost:8080/studentID=100

The problem is that the user could change the value of parameter studentID and get the details of some other student which he/she is not eligible to see (hence not shown in the previous list screen). This is a security issue - url manipulation.

I could think of some the ways we could prevent this.

Comment: Prakash's answer is the best starting place - but from the question it sounds like you are looking for a more granular security - what defines what students a user can see? is it as simple as a user can either see students or not (in which case basic role-based security will do) or is it that a user can only see select groups of students(e.g. a teacher can only see students they teach)? the latter would prob be easiest to solve with role based plus controller level validation/checking that the request is valid

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cookies and unique session ids. So a user logs in and is given a unique key which is corresponding to a database table with these temporary  access token or session id. Usually these tokens are only valid for a period of time. On the server side you can test the cookie value to database and redirect users that are not allowed access. Good luck, your asking the right questions just keep going!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open separate window. Here is some example. Im using Jquery here.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>
```

Sample HTML

```
<div id="blockbox" >

    <div class="contents">
        <div id="data"></div>
        <div class="close">close</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
<a href="#" stid='1'>Name1</a>
<a href="#" stid='2'>Name2</a>
<a href="#" stid='3'>Name3</a>
<a href="#" stid='4'>Name4</a>
<a href="#" stid='5'>Name5</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.contents
{

    color:#111;
    font-family: "Calibri";
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000;
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-top:20%;
    padding: 16px;
    z-index:2000;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.contents .close
{
    width: 20px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#blockbox").fadeOut(0);

    $("div a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
       $("#blockbox").fadeIn(100);
        //$("#data").html($(this).attr("stid"));

        //This will sent studentID to relevent page
        //and retrieve the result
        $.post("myhost:8080", 
        {
            studentID:$(this).attr("stid"),
        }
        ).done(function(data) {
            $("#data").html(data);
        });
    });

     $(".close").click(function(e){
       $("#blockbox").fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```

Your server side script catch the studentID sent by the $.post method. Im using php here

```
<?php
$studentID=$_POST['studentID'];
//echo student details
?>
```

Then data variable catch the response and added it to #data id

```
.done(function(data) {
            $("#data").html(data);
        });
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/sjnilan/UUbj2/#run)

Answer (score 0):

Implement Role based security using Spring Framework

For tutorial You may refer:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-access-control-example/